# EF Core 3.1 searching filter

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I am trying to create search filter with a lot of options (string input, select input ...). I need to filter tags by category if categoryId more than 0,  if categoryId equals 0 return all tags with all related categories (or don't apply category option for searching). But my code doesn't return any categories in both cases, and doesn't give me any mistakes. A lot of examples in the internet that I found shows how work just one string input.

```
        IQueryable<Tag> tags = _context.Tag
                                .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.Name, "%" + name + "%"))
                                .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.Description, "%" + description + "%"))
                                .Include(s => s.Value)
                                .Include(s => s.Period);     
        if (categoryId > 0)
        {
            tags.Include(s => s.Category).Where(s => s.Category.CategoryId == categoryId);
        }
        else
        {
            tags.Include(s => s.Category);
        }
```

Could anyone explain why my code doesn't work? And how to implement this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: You must use the return value of the fluent calls in order to have effect. e.g. `tags.Include(s => s.Category)` -> `tags = tags.Include(s => s.Category)`

Answer (score 0):

Right code is:

```
IQueryable<Tag> tags = _context.Tag
                            .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.Name, "%" + name + "%"))
                            .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.Description, "%" + description + "%"))
                            .Include(s => s.Value)
                            .Include(s => s.Period);     
    if (categoryId > 0)
    {
        tags = tags.Include(s => s.Category).Where(s => s.Category.CategoryId == categoryId);
    }
    else
    {
        tags = tags.Include(s => s.Category);
    }
```